# Add new experimenter match field in OVS source code

Tags: c, openvswitch

I would like to add new match field of type OXM_experimenter class OVS source code, could anyone share proper document or steps to do it. It needs changes in many of the files and functions and understanding OVS source is somewhat difficult. If any added already and tested, can you guide ?

Answer (score 0):

I successfully did this before, however, I don't have access to the code anymore, only bookmarks to stuff. There is an old thread in the mailing lists that may help you: [Link](https://mail.openvswitch.org/pipermail/ovs-discuss/2015-May/037398.html) and [Link](https://mail.openvswitch.org/pipermail/ovs-discuss/2015-May/037560.html).

I wanted to handle PACKET_IN events in OVS a bit differently, so I followed the way of packets from the data plane through the upcall bit to `ofproto-dpif-xlate.c`. On the way, I stumbled upon a lot of constants. After adding my own to the enums, the last bit missing was the experimenter field, which was somewhere in the python scripts as described in the links above.

I hope this helps, I'm in the process of getting access to the code again I'll update my answer then. If not, the OvS discuss [mailing list](http://openvswitch.org/mlists/) and [archives](https://mail.openvswitch.org/pipermail/ovs-discuss/) may help you too.